# Does Kalman Filter using pykalman on linear trends give correct answers?

Tags: python, kalman-filter, pykalman

I am trying to use `KalmanFilter` to estimate the mean value of a series but I was unable to find much information related to it for linear trends, so I was trying to use it to predict the values when the input is just a straight line with positive slope.

```
from pykalman import KalmanFilter as KF
y=np.arange(0,100,1)
y=pd.DataFrame(y)
x=y.shift(1)
x=pd.DataFrame(x,index=np.arange(0,100,1))
kf = KF(transition_matrices = [1],
    observation_matrices = [1],
    initial_state_mean = 10,
    initial_state_covariance = 1,
    observation_covariance=1,
    transition_covariance=.01)

state_means, _ = kf.filter(x.dropna().values)
d={'a':np.asarray(x),'b':np.asarray(state_means)}
sm = pd.DataFrame(state_means,index=x.index[:-1],columns=['state'])
sma=x.rolling(window=10).mean()
x['kalman']=sm
x['rolling']=sma
x.plot(figsize=(10,8))
```

I was able to **apply** it but I am not sure if this is correct or not. I am seeing a gap between the actual values and the kalman state means: [image: graph].

I thought that KalmanFilter will just finish that gap and eventually coincide with the straight line but they seem to be parallel after a while.

Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i modified your code:https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1URN0ozgEBJmj3yos_84_2dYDc29Hc-ec?usp=sharing

check that

Comment: @bakaDev Your notebook is private

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I've shared in the comments.

```
from pykalman import KalmanFilter as KF
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y=np.arange(0,100,1)
y=pd.DataFrame(y)
x=y.shift(1)
x=pd.DataFrame(x,index=np.arange(0,100,1))
kf = KF(initial_state_mean=0, n_dim_obs=1)
#kf = kf.em(x.dropna().values, n_iter=5)
state_means, _ = kf.filter(x.dropna().values)
d={'a':np.asarray(x),'b':np.asarray(state_means)}
sm = pd.DataFrame(state_means,index=x.index[:-1],columns=['state'])
sma=x.rolling(window=10).mean()
x['kalman']=sm
x['rolling']=sma
x.plot(figsize=(10,8))
```

[image]

Comment: But your code does prove that the kalmanFilter line should eventually coincide with the data and hence it proves that my code is wrong too

Comment: Hey. I added some code in your notebook. Can you please check if it's wrong?

Comment: can u share your notebook, cause my notebook only hand view permission and as the result your notebook is a copy.

Comment: So, I was actually able to figure out what was happening by looking at the source code of pykalman. Adding transition_matrices and transition_covariance was causing the problem because we don't need the states to be dependent on the previous state; just the new observation. It worked fine after that. I actually wanted to use it to find the regression slope between two datas and I was able to use pykalman and I also wrote the basic code using kalman filter theory and both are giving the exact same answers.